# How to prepend a JS event handler in Prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

I would like to add an event listener/handler to be prepended before an existing event handler in Prototype. Here is the example:

```
<form ... onsubmit="alert('foo')" id="f1">
   $('f1').observe("submit", function() {
     alert('do this before foo');
   });
</form>
```

Comment: I would suggest not relying on order of bindings...perhaps there is another way to do what you want.  Make the onsubmit have a function which triggers a different custom event before doing what it was doing....

Comment: Excellent point, I think I might have just found the solution. The background of my question is a Rails remote_form(), which adds the onsubmit Ajax call. Now I could just add a create call on this Ajax request to prepend the other event handler. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Observer = Class.create({
 initialize: function() {
  this.callbacks = [];
 },
 prependCallback = function(callback) {
  this.callbacks.unshift(callback);
 },
 appendCallback = function(callback) {
  this.callbacks.push(callback);
 },
 runCallbacks = function() {
  this.callbacks.each(
   function(callback) {
    callback();
   }
  );
 }
});

bunchOfCallbacks = new Observer();
bunchOfCallbacks.appendCallback(function(){alert('second');});
$('anything').observe('anyEvent', bunchOfCallbacks.runCallbacks);
bunchOfCallbacks.prependCallback(function(){alert('first');});
```